# ExtJS change position of default buttons in MessageBox (ExtJS 4.2.1)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

If you use the code with the default buttons:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
 title:'Save Changes?',
 msg: 'You are closing a tab that has unsaved changes. Would you like to save your changes?',
 buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
 icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
});
```

the buttons on the window are in the order yes - no - cancel. I would like them in the order cancel - no - yes for consistency in my app. Is there a way to add a different configuration or change this for my needs?

Comment: Did you try using ```buttons: [
            {text: 'Cancel', itemId: 'cancel'},
            {text: 'No',     itemId: 'no'},
            {text: 'Yes',    itemId: 'yes', ui: 'action'}
        ]```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default buttons is simply created within [Ext.window.MessageBox.makeButton()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/MessageBox.html#Ext-window-MessageBox-method-makeButton) private method based on [Ext.window.MessageBox.buttonIds](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/MessageBox.html#Ext-window-MessageBox-property-buttonIds) config and show / hide based on bitmask `buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL`.

So we just have to override `buttonIds` config and bitmasks:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.overrides.MessageBox', {
        override: 'Ext.window.MessageBox',

        OK: 1,           //0001
        CANCEL: 2,       //0010
        NO: 4,           //0100
        YES: 8,          //1000

        OKCANCEL: 3,     //0011
        YESNO: 12,       //1100
        YESNOCANCEL: 14, //1110

        buttonIds: [
            'ok', 'cancel', 'no', 'yes'
        ]
    });
```

`Ext.Msg` / `Ext.MessageBox` is singletones and initially defined as instance of `Ext.window.MessageBox` **before** our override (check last lines of [Ext.MessageBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/MessageBox.html#Ext-MessageBox) code).

So we have to override `Ext.Msg` / `Ext.MessageBox` aswell:

```
    Ext.Msg = Ext.MessageBox = new Ext.window.MessageBox();
```

Check this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sbr).

Comment: Instead of overriding we can just use config for buttons instead of already provided set of buttons. See my comment on original question.

Comment: @bunkdeath, if we want to use this button order in whole application - its better to override.

Comment: Yes. After re-reading the question. I felt overriding will do good for development because of the order they have in their app. (y)

Comment: But Override have a serious problem ..It will effect other button alignments

Comment: Try with remaining buttons Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,  Ext.MessageBox.YESNO the buttons will change check my fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sbn

Comment: @surya-prakash-tumma True! forgot to update bitmasks. Check update.